# How to load list in select from field using [fromcontrol] in Angular?

Tags: angular8

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [formControl]="animalControl" required>
    <mat-option>all</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let animal of animals" [value]="animal">
      {{animal.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

How to load list `animals` using `formControl`?

Best efficiency way.

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: No, Sir but in need best efficient way for multiple lists